# convert multidimensional numpy array to image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

I have a numpy array(trainData.npy) for image processing. It contains 2000 images, garyscale and height 450 , width 600.

Train images shape:(2000, 1, 450, 600)

I'm looking for a way to plot or show one of these images. I've used this code but i'v got TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data error/

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = img_train[0]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: maybe you first should check for the `shape` of your `img`

Comment: I've already done. img_train[0].shape the answer is (1, 450, 600)

Comment: image show can show two dimensional arrays. `img = img_train[0,0]`

Answer (score 1):

Just reshape your image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = img_train[0] #img has dim (ncolor=1, nlines=450, nrows=600)
img = reshape(450, 600) #img has dim (450, 600)
#img = img / img.max #if you need rescaling of greyscale to be in [0..1]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

P.S.: I personally find it a bit more intuitive if pictures are dimensional-ordered `(nlines, nrows, ncolorchanel)` than your choice `(ncolorchanel, nlines, nrows)`

Comment: img = img.reshape(450, 600) it worked great. Thanks!